# How to Can I solve this error= "NoSuchMethodrror: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'statusCode'."

Tags: json, flutter, rest, http, post

I was working with rest api in flutter but I get error when I want create post options. I created task with post. I want solve this error. I have given the necessary code structures in the description. I hope I was able to explain clearly
Code Here:
My BaseClientClass

```
  Future<dynamic> post(String baseUrl, String api, dynamic payloadObj) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + api);
    String payload = json.encode(payloadObj);
    try {
      var response = await http.post(uri, body: payload, headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: TIME_OUT_DURATION));
      return _procosessResponse(response);
    } on SocketException {
      throw FetchDataException('No Internet connection', uri.toString());
    } on TimeoutException {
      throw ApiNotRespondingException(
          'API not responded in time', uri.toString());
    }
  }
```

Controller class

```
Future postTodo(String task, bool active) async {
    Map msg = {
      "task": task,
      "active": active
    };
    // String jsonS= json.encode(msg);

    var response = await baseClient.post(
        "http://192.168.1.114:5000", '/api/task', msg);
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonData['success']) { // eğer succes true ise

        todolist.add(TodoModel.fromJson(jsonData['data']));
        // var jsonData = json.encode(response);
        print(msg);
      }
    }
```

add task Widget class

```
class AddTaskWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController? task;
  VoidCallback? onPress;

  AddTaskWidget({this.task, this.onPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: AlertDialog(
        content: TextFormField(
          controller: task,
        ),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text("İptal")),
          TextButton(onPressed: onPress, child: Text("Ekle"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This call post function and task widget code

```
IconButton(
              onPressed: () => showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) => AddTaskWidget(
                        task: todoController.textTaskNameController,
                        onPress: () async{
                          await todoController.postTodo(
                              todoController.textTaskNameController.text, true);
                          Navigator.pop(context);

                        }),
                  ),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add))
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide the API response payload once in JSON format

Comment: I have already done it in BAseClient class.